# Add custom resource to Silverlight application with pre-build event

Tags: .net, silverlight, resources, pre-build-event

I want to add source code of my silverlight project to resource as flat text files (for use in run-time with `Application.GetResourceStream()`). How I can do it without pre-build event of my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible. You should use pre-build events.